# Way to define marginal probabilities

Tags: self-study, random-variable, notation

I found this notation in one paper that focuses on copulas:

> Consider a $d$ -dimensional continuous random vector $X=\left\{X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots X_{d}\right\}$ with marginals $F_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)=$ $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i} \leq x_{i}\right) .$ Given a $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d},$ the distribution function $F(x)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1} \leq x_{1}, \cdots X_{d} \leq x_{d}\right)$ specifies
> all marginal distributions $F_{i}\left(x_{i}\right)$ as well as any dependencies between $X$.

I understood $X_i$ are random variables. I would kindly ask what is the $x_i$ in this case.
It should also be random variable, but then there is just $x$ which is a random vector then.

When I think of marginal probabilities I imagine something like this:

|  | $X_1$ | $X_2$ | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 10 | 20 | 30 |
|  | 30 | 10 | 40 |
|  | 20 | 10 | 30 |
| Totals | **60** | **40** | **100** |

So marginal probabilities are these form the M column.
So isn't it better to define the marginal probabilities with the uppercase letter, just for consistency.
Your sanity may help me understand the notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a random vector made of random variables as components. For instance, $X=(X_1,X_2)$ with $X_1\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ and $X_2|X_1\sim\mathcal N(-2X_1,2^2)$ is such a thing. The marginal distribution of $X_1$ is $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and the marginal distribution of $X_2$ is $\mathcal N(0,8)$

The joint cdf is defined as
$$F(x)=F(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,\cdots,X_n\le x_n)$$
where $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$. In the above example,
$$F(x)=F(x_1,x_2)=\mathbb P(X_1\le x_1,X_2\le x_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \varphi(x_1)\Phi([x_2+2x_1]/2)\,\text dx_1$$
It defines marginal distributions${}^*$ through their cdfs
$$F_i(x_i)=F(+\infty,\ldots,\underbrace{+\infty,x_i,+\infty,}_\text{$i$-th position}\ldots,+\infty)$$

---

<sub>${}^*$I do not understand the table produced in the question, as the probabilities (?) do not add up to 100.</sub>

Comment: Are the $x_i$ scalars then?

Comment: I will gladly accept the answer if you touch the later casing part.

Comment: Am I wrong when I imagine $x_i$ is a sum of $i$-th state of random variables $X_i$? You see my upper table and just replace $M$ with $x$ then.

Comment: OK, this is how I see the marginal probabilities, imagine a table full of numbers, two columns tree rows. Just like one I made in the question. Third column represent the marginal probabilities for the $i$-th value of the random variable. So the column $M$ in the image is random variable itself because it is the sum. If this is the case column $M$ represents a random variable.

Comment: The table is not appropriate because the rows would correspond to the possible values of the rv $X_1$ while the columns would correspond to the possible values of the rv $X_2$.

Comment: OK, I added the sum to 100 which has sense but if you imagine you may have random variables Man, Woman as columns and many rows each representing how many ice-cream they eat per day. What you suggest each new RV adds a new dimension.

Comment: Gender would be the random variable $X_1$ with possible values "female" and "male" while the number of ice-creams per day would be the random variable $X_2$. These two random variables have a joint distribution given by a contingency table.